# How to prove a function is one-to-one(injective)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How do I prove that this function is one-to-one(injective)?

$f : \Bbb N \rightarrow \Bbb Z$

$f(x) = x^2 + 3x - 4$

I know a function is one-to-one if $f(a)=f(b) \implies a=b$.

But I don't know how to prove that for this function

Comment: Well, for one thing it is strictly increasing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ And assume $f(x) = f(y)$. Then,

$$x^2 + 3x - 4 = y^2 + 3y -4$$
$$x^2 - y^2 = 3(y - x) $$
$$(x-y)(x+y) = -3(x-y) $$
Assume that $x \ne y$, then $x - y \ne 0$, so we can divide both sides by this quantity.
$$(x+y) = -3$$
$$x = -(3+y) $$
$y > 0$ since $y \in \mathbb{N}$, so $x < 0$ by the equation above. However this contradicts the fact that $x > 0$, as $x \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus the assumption that $x \ne y $ is false, and so $f(x) = f(y) $ implies $x = y $.

Therefore $f $ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

A function is injective if no 2 values map to the same point. Assume this was not so, then you could find integers $m \ne n$ with $f(m) = f(n)$. Can you find a problem with this?